# Regex: How to find exact value length?

Tags: java, regex

I got these several cases of given String:

1. key1=12345
2. key1=12345&key2=12345
3. key1=12345123456789
4. key1=12345123456789&key2=123456789

Using this pattern: `(key1)=([^&]{5})(|$))`.

The expected results are:

1. 12345
2. 12345, 12345
3. nothing
4. nothing

And while running, the results were:

1. 12345
2. 12345, 12345
3. 12345
4. 12345, 12345

Which means that the `{5}` is actually **cutting** the text by the given length which is `5` and not looking for exact `5`. 
How can I make it to look for exact `5` and not to cut the text ?

Comment: Why does row #3 give you an expected result of nothing?

Comment: this is just the expected result, It should be nothing because the part after `=` is more then `5`

Comment: It is looking for an exact 5. Say your wife asks you for 10 dollars. Will you a) tell her "Sorry, I don't have $10, I only have $283", or will you b) give her the first $10 you find in your wallet? With regexp you need to tell it "five of what I want in between of things I don't want".

Comment: @Amadan I'd give always give her all I have but that's another story...

Comment: I need ONLY `5` case, how can I make it?

Comment: Just use `\b` - word boundaries. [`String pattern = "(key\\d+)=\\b([^&]{5})\\b";`](https://regex101.com/r/kB6dH0/1)

Comment: Also, `(key)` can't match `"key1"`.

Comment: the boundries can be end of line or `&`

Comment: Just a hint: An empty alternative like `(|$)` effectively makes this group optional which suggests the alternative is completely redundant.

Comment: "while running" what code exactly? Are you using a `Matcher`? If so, what groups are you selecting etc. Please post your code.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't give the result that you said you are getting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will do it:

```
=([^&]{5})(?:&|$)
```

It finds `=`, followed by 5 captured characters that are not `&`, immediately be followed by either `&` or the end of the string.

**Test**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("key1=12345");
    test("key1=12345&key2=12345");
    test("key1=12345123456789");
    test("key1=12345123456789&key2=123456789");
}
private static void test(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("=([^&]{5})(?:&|$)").matcher(input);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find())
        list.add(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

*Output*

```
[12345]
[12345, 12345]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Was helpful, how can I improve this pattern to fetch several cases of one String ?

Comment: @TheDr. Not following you. This code *is* fetching both values in the second case.

Comment: could you please explain the part of `(?:&|$)` in the pattern, for what it's used for ?

Comment: @TheDr. The second example has two values. The first ends at the `&` character. The second ends at the end of text which in regex is identified by the special character `$` (similar to `^` which matches the start of text). The special character `|` means OR, so `&` OR end-of-text is `&|$`. Like in Java, the parenthesis scopes the expression, so `(&|$)`, but that would make it a capture group too, and we don't need to capture the `&`, so we use the non-capturing construct `(?:X)` for a final regex of `(?:&|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you must add boundaries somehow. One can use anchors for that (such as `\b` for "word boundary", or `^` and `$` for string/line boundary). Other way is to limit match until a given character appears - e.g `[^&\n]` - not until the `&` sign or a newline, then check the length programmaticaly in Java.

I came up with a regex of my own: [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vU1mZ5/1)

`(?:=)(\d{5})(?:[&|\n])`

- First of all I look for a `=` sign, but do not capture it.
- Then I look for 5 digits...
- ... followed either by `&` sign or a newline (which I do not capture either)

If you need to look only for `key1, key2` values, just add `(?:key\d=)` instead of `(?:=)` - [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU1mZ5/2)

Then the only matches found are of given length.

[@Stribizhev's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307354/regex-how-to-find-exact-value-length/34307441#comment56356441_34307354) might be potentially more secure and more false-positive protected, though.

Comment: Not  a direct answer, but an answer :)

Comment: Could you use please combine my pattern with your solution ?

Comment: @stribizhev I'm currently working on a regex that might suit the needs of the OP, but for now I wanted to let him know of the other way possible :)

Comment: Just use the regex from my comment and explain it.

Comment: What you used is the same as `=(\d{5})[&\n]`. Match a `=`, then capture 5 digits followed by a `&` or `\n`. No need using non-capturing groups here and a `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` symbol, it is no longer an alternation operator.

Comment: This doesn't work, because OP has 4 test cases of a single string, not a 4-line string. There are no linefeeds in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
([^=&]+)=(?<![^=&])([^=&]{5})(?![^=&])
```

key, then `=`, then five characters that are not `=` or `&`, not surrounded by more characters that are not `=` or `&`. (`\b` is useful in limited circumstances where your values are guaranteed to only consist of letters, numbers and underscores; negative lookaround is much more general).